# Design 2 interactive modules in Ocaml

Tags: module, ocaml

I would like to design 2 modules `A` and `B` which both have their own functions, for instance: `A.compare: A.t -> A.t -> bool`, `B.compare: B.t -> B.t -> bool`. The elements of `A` and `B` are convertible. So I would also need functions `a_of_b : B.t -> A.t` and `b_of_a : A.t -> B.t`. My question is where I should define these functions? inside the structure of `A` or the one of `B` or somewhere else?

Could anyone help?

**Edit1:** just amended some errors based on the first comment

Comment: I'm not sure the modules are interactive, they are perhaps interdependent or related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic design problem. In OOP languages, it is hard to resolve this elegantly because a class encapsulates both a type definition and methods related to that type. Thus, as soon as you have a function such as a_of_b, which regards two types to an equal extent, there is no clear place for it.

OCaml correctly provides distinct language mechanisms for these distinct needs: type definitions are introduced with the keyword `type`, and related methods are collected together in a `module`. This gives you greater flexibility in designing your API, but does not solve the problem automatically.

One possibility is to define modules A and B, both with their respective types and compare functions. Then, the question remaining is where to put `a_of_b` and `b_of_a`. You could arbitrarily give preference to module A, and define the functions `A.to_b` and `A.of_b`. This is what the Standard Library did when it put `to_list` and `of_list` in Array. This lacks symmetry; there is no reason not to have put these functions in B instead.

Instead you could standardize on using `of_` functions vs `to_` functions. Let's say you prefer `to_`. Then you would define the functions `A.to_b` and `B.to_a`. The problem now is modules A and B are mutually dependent, which is only possible if you define them in the same file.

If you will have lots of functions that deal with values of type `A.t` and `B.t`, then it may be worth defining a module AB, and putting all these functions in there. If you will only need two, then an extra module is perhaps overkill.

On the other hand, if the total number of functions regarding A's and B's is small, you could create only the module AB, with `type a`, `type b`, and all related methods. However, this does not follow the OCaml community's convention of naming a type `t` within its own module, and it will be harder to apply the Set and Map functors to these types.

Comment: Thanks for your comments... I am still interested in how to define a module AB which include A and B, in this case, is it better to make `AB.A.to_b` and `AB.A.of_b`, or `AB.a_of_b` and `AB.b_of_a`?

Comment: If you define `A.to_b` and `A.of_b`, then I don't see why you would want module `AB` at all. It would contain nothing but the modules `A` and `B`, and I don't see the benefit of adding an extra layer to your module hierarchy. And whether you should define `A.to_b` and `A.of_b` vs `AB.a_of_b` and `AB.b_of_a` is a matter of choice. I provided some criteria to consider.

Comment: One reason to have a module AB containing sub-modules A & B is that your want to have a single file ab.ml & ab.mli (and not a.ml, b.ml, a.mli, b.mli).

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean `A.compare: A.t -> A.t -> bool` because types are in lower cases.

You can have a single module AB which contains both the type for A and the type for B.

You can have a single module AB containing both A & B as sub-modules.

You might also use [recursive modules](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual021.html#toc75)  & functors.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... Actually from outside, I would like to be able to call `A.compare` or `B.compare` whenever I want. So if define them in a single module `AB`, how could I call them from outside? `AB.A.compare` and `AB.B.compare`?

Comment: Yes, `AB.A.compare` and `AB.B.compare`

Comment: and `AB.a_of_b` and `AB.b_of_a`? so this is about which implementation you mentionned: the first or the second?

Comment: You can mix things. I did not understood fully your original requirements.